# connect my plugin to woo commerce payment system

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a plugin and I want to connect my plugin to `WooCommerce` payment system.

so when user wants to buy something plugin uses the WooCommerce gateway and then redirect the info to my plugin
its because I don't want to write gateway codes and WooCommerce has all these codes ready

Is this possible?

```
<div>
    <a href="" id="buy">buy</a>
</div>
```

after the user clicked the link page goes to the gateway and the result goes back to my plugin.

Comment: well yeah.. you have no href?

Comment: i did not wrote my code yet. i dont know where to begin

Answer (score 0):

you can try that

```
// create the order

$price = 123.45;

$order = wc_create_order();

$order->set_billing_first_name("client name");
$order->set_created_via("created by MyPlugin");

$item = new \WC_Order_Item_Product();
$item->set_props([
    "name" => "product name",
    "total" => $price,
]);

$order->add_item($item);
$order->set_total($price);

$order->save();


// redirect to checkout page for the payment

$order_received_url = wc_get_endpoint_url( 'order-received', $order->get_id(), wc_get_checkout_url() );
$order_received_url = add_query_arg( 'key', $order->get_order_key(), $order_received_url );

wp_redirect($order_received_url);
exit();
```

Comment: its great but i want to redirect user to gateway to pay for product

Comment: in your question you say that you want to use the woocommerce gateway already in place. if you want to customise the gateway, it's another question then you have to create a new question.

Comment: i dont want to create gateway. i want to redirect the customer to one of available gateways whithout seeing the checkout page